# Word order for names

Tags: programming-practices, naming

I'm working with a team of non-native English speakers and I'm struggling to come up with a rule that explains why a method should be called `getFilePath` and not `getPathFile`.

Examples of this bad naming come up on a daily basis and except for just pointing out the better name, I cannot figure out a good way to explain why words should be in a specific order, except for "It how it's written in English". Especially for variable names like this one since none of its components are adjectives.

I realize this is very basic and probably second nature to everyone here, but I think that's why I'm struggling to figure out how to explain it to people who don't understand it.

How would you explain it?

Comment: see [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: Word order is crucial in English. There are very few so-called "postpositive adjectives", and they appear almost entirely in archaic language. If the code is to be written in English, then the simple answer is that the code must comply with principles of English - you can say "FilePath" or "PathOfFile", but "PathFile" is not correct, unless it obviously complies with a naming convention as would be perceived and understood by English-speaking developers in a context (e.g. GetDateBirth, GetDateMarried, GetDateDeath, where it is understood that all methods relate to getting the dates of things).

Comment: English contains possessive nouns, whereas many other languages do not. So `getFilePath` is just a contraction of "*get file's path*". In other languages, it would be expressed in the form "*get path of file*". That's why expressing it as `getPathFile` makes sense to folk who do not have English as their first language. But in English it reads as "get path's file" which is the wrong way around.

Comment: @DavidArno awesome explanation!

Comment: @DavidArno if you elaborated on your comment in an answer, I'd love to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Tell your team that the verb is related to the last word of the identified, and that the other words in-between give additional details, the importance of which is decreasing from right to left.  So, if they want to get a path it's `getPath()`.  If they want to say it's the path of the file, they add the detail in-between `getFilePath()`. if this file path is long, they could add this extra detail:  `getLongFilePath()`.

Conversely, you can propose a self-assessment test: *would a simplified identifier with only the first and last word still be accurate* ?

```
    getPath() -> getPath() :  ok 
    getFilePath() -> getPath() : ok
    getPathFile() -> getFile() : not ok, because the string of the path is not a file descriptior.
```

**Solution 2:**

Organise some workshop on writing better identifiers.  The best would be to do this with a language trainer who could focus on how to build nice simple [nominal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_group_(functional_grammar)) in English.

Comment: file.OpenText()

Answer (score 5):

> I cannot figure out a good way to explain why words should be in a
>   specific order, except for "It how it's written in English"

That's because it is the only reason for writing it this way.

There is a naive view that there is a consensus that all programming should be done in american English. But this isn't really the case, let the developers choose names that *they* understand. Add intellisense comments for alternate languages

Comment: Well... yes... but... IF you go with English, you might as well do it right according to English rules. And if you are in a non-English environment where there is the slightest chance that some foreigner will have to do maintenance or review on the code, there is a lot to say for doing everything in English from the start.

Comment: ...which does bring new challenges to some as the ones pointed out in the question. Up to the point that it is hard to understand what they even mean. With some comments or issue descriptions encountered  I have to translate back to my native language, in the most literal way possible, in order to understand what the writer meant to say. :-)

Comment: @MartinMaat tell that the microsoft with their "color" and "deserialization" etc!!

Comment: Yeah the thing is that it's an existing codebase written and maintained in American English, and we want to keep it consistent.

Comment: @Ewan https://i.pinimg.com/736x/9d/bf/dd/9dbfdd5a366ccaa137a550dab77fde47--family-photo-album-funny-family.jpg

Comment: It's not just important that the programmers understand what their name means.  It's also (at least as) important that the people who come along later to maintain the code can also understand it.  Names that don't make sense won't help the maintainers.

Comment: @FranSevillano well that's a fair enough reason, but there's no logic to english thats just the way it is

Comment: @SimonB the problem there is that you are assuming things about your future developers. maybe they french speak, non?

Answer (score 5):

"File Path" is a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase#Identification). You want to find a way to explain the syntax of noun phrases in english, in particular where the **head noun** appears (at the end in this and similar phrases), and that the the value returned should be an instance of the thing named by the head noun.

Your function presumably returns a path, in particular the path of a file. If you swap the words you would imply that it would return a file, of the sort that relates to a path.

Comment: Cook.EggsBenedict